# How do I link local Frameworks with CMake

Tags: macos, cmake

Have no issues linking to system frameworks, but I can't ever seem to get CMake to find pre-built frameworks stored in a local directory.  Tried various combinations of find_library and link_directories.

```
link_directories(/path/to/Framework)

find_library(THE_FRAMEWORK
             NAMES TheFramework
             HINT "/path/to/Framework"
             REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${THE_FRAMEWORK})
```

I invariably end up with a NOT_FOUND error.

Comment: If replacing `HINT` with `HINTS` helps, then it is just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue was that HINT needed to be HINTS